# How do I execute onSubscribe action of do operator in Main thread

Tags: rx-swift

I execute UI related operation in the `onSubscribe` action of `do` operator. I obtain an

> Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread

console error in Xcode. I tried to use `observe(on: MainScheduler.instance)` but without success.

This my snippet:

```
 checkCurrentNetworkAndConnect().observe(on: MainScheduler.instance).do(onSubscribe: {
      // UI related stuff
 })
```

I also tried with `subscribe(on: MainScheduler.instance)` but doesn't work.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: The problem here is that you are trying to do a UI related operation in the `onSubscribe` of the `do` operator. This is a mistake. Tell us more about why you want to do this and maybe we can show you a better way to accomplish the task.

Comment: Thank @DanielT. What I'm trying to achieve is update a label text when `checkCurrentNetworkAndConnect` operation effectively starts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will happen if you are calling `subscribe` on a background thread. If you call subscribe on a background thread, then the Observable will be subscribed to on that background thread. To solve this, you will need to use `subscribe(on:)` *after* the `do` operator...

Something like this:

```
func example() {
    checkCurrentNetworkAndConnect()
        .do(onSubscribe: {
            print("UI related stuff")
        })
        .subscribe(on: MainScheduler.instance)
        .subscribe()
}
```

With the above, even if you call `example()` on a background thread, the `onSubscribe:` closure will be executed on the main thread.

If for some reason you also want the `checkCurrentNetworkAndConnect()` on a background thread, then you can do that with another `subscribe(on:)` above the `do`.

All this said, you should not be performing significant side effects inside a `do(onSubscribe:)` in the first place. It's one thing to put debug code in there but not anything more than that. I've been using RxSwift for 6 years and I've never needed to use a `do(onSubscribe:)` at all, much less for significant code. There is likely a better way to accomplish the ultimate goal you are trying to accomplish.

---

In response to your comment. How you go about doing what you want depends very much on specifics not provided. Below I have made some simplifying assumptions. If your problem is different, I suggest you post a new question with the details...

```
func example(operations: [Observable<Void>], messages: [String], label: UILabel, disposeBag: DisposeBag) {
    Observable.concat(operations.enumerated().map { index, op in
        op.map { messages[index + 1] }
    })
        .startWith(messages[0])
        .observe(on: MainScheduler.instance)
        .bind(to: label.rx.text)
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
}
```

The code above assumes:

- that you have an array of operations expressed as observables
- that none of them need data provided by a previous operation
- that none of them emit data you care to use or keep
- that every operation has a message that needs to be displayed before the operation starts
- that there is an additional message to be displayed when the last operation completes

Comment: Thanks @Daniel T. I'm new to RxSwift (I've been using it for only a week) so I take this opportunity to explain you what I want to achieve. I have to execute a sequence of operations one by one..and when an operation is about to start, I want update a loader label to notify user about the current operation.

Comment: I updated my answer.

Comment: Hi @Daniel T., I opened another question at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69931230/how-can-execute-operations-sequentially-and-update-ui). I'd like you to look at it. Thanks very much for your help.